# Paréntesis, rayas o comas con dos puntos

Tags: puntuación

> Soy una perfeccionista apasionada por los idiomas, incluida mi lengua materna: el árabe.

¿Cómo se debe puntuar esta frase antes de "incluida" y "el árabe"? ¿Se puede/debe usar paréntesis o rayas en vez de la coma? ¿Y qué tal los dos puntos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los dos puntos son gramaticalmente correctos pero le dan demasiada relevancia a una frase muy corta como "el árabe". Además, su uso me parece más adecuado cuando se introduce una verdadera conclusión, por ejemplo:

- Recurrí al único idioma que dominaba y que podía ayudarme en esas circunstancias **: el árabe**. (Nótese que lo que precede a los dos puntos genera suficiente "suspenso" como para que el uso de los dos puntos sea realmente justificado.)

Además, al haber modificado "incluso" (que a mi entender es incorrecto) (ver [aquí](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=8thfqpmeuD6GYk7oXl)) por "incluida", se genera un conflicto de género entre "idiomas" e "incluida".

Por ambas razones, corregiría la oración como sigue:

- Soy una perfeccionista apasionada por los idiomas, **incluido** el árabe, mi lengua materna.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Gustavson. De veras aprecio su ayuda.

Comment: @Mariam Si hablas inglés te puede ayudar saber que "incluso" por lo general se traduce como "*even*" e "incluido/a/s" como "*including*". Claramente, en la traducción de tu oración al inglés "*even*" no sería posible.

Comment: Entiendo, Gustavson. Sí, hablo inglés. Comprendo a lo que se refiere. Muchas gracias. :)